# Kafka Streams Sticky Task assignment interfering with Task Load Balancing when clients start sequentially

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm seeing some KStreams behaviour which may be a bug / unintended feature and was wondering if anybody else also has dealt with this before

Scenario:

One application that contains two subtopologies. One of these subtopologies requires more ressources than the other. Each subtopology has multiple tasks / input partitions per topic.

There are two instances running this application. These instances start sequentially. What I was expecting to see from the implemented findLeastLoaded Task Load Balancing was more or less equal distribution of both subtopologies' tasks across both instances.

However what I am actually seeing is one client getting all tasks from one subtopology (requires few ressources) while the other client gets all the tasks from the other, heavy subtopology (requites much more resources). This essentially prevents proper horizontal scaling

After some thought and debugging I am pretty sure that Sticky Tasks are to blame for this, in combination with ordered task assignment.

Client 1 starts and gets assigned all tasks IN ORDER (this is important. It is ordering by Subtopology:Partition. The ordering means that all the light tasks are distributed first, then the heavy tasks are distributed)

These tasks now become sticky.

Then Client 2 joins the group after some time. The sticky reassignment logic causes the light tasks that were distributed in order to stay on client 1. The remaining ordered sticky tasks that go over client 1's threshold capacity (which happen to be all the heavy tasks) are now moved to client 2.

Did anybody deal with this before and find a solution that does not involve changing the internal partition assignment code?

Comment: Proper load balancing is tricky and there are some known issues. What versions are you using? Some issues are already fixed in newer version. -- Also upcoming 2.6 release will contain an improved load-balancing algorithm.

Comment: We're using 2.3. I've already noticed the improvements in the 2.6 dev branch, but unfortunately this is a bit time critical.. As a workaround we're now starting one Kafka Streams Instance per subtopology per machine, so multiple kafka streams in one application. This essentially causes data-parallel task distribution as in 2.6, though it's a bit hacky